# The second most popular way of making journeys is on foot

Tags: writing, ielts, academic-writing

I'm checking this chart's description:

[image]

There is one sentence that sounds odd

```
The second most popular way of making journeys in Canada is on foot.
```

I think that `way of making journeys` doesn't sound natural.

Would it be better to write

```
The second most popular means of transport in Canada is on foot?
```

I'm also not sure about `on foot` here. Is `on foot` ok in a sentence like this?

It's an IELTS writing task, so the style should be academic.

Will appreciate any clarifications.

Comment: It's a strange thing to say. In reality. For almost all people who have ever lived, ***walking*** (travelling "on foot") would be by far the "most popular" way of getting from place to place. But doubtless in this modern age there are quite a few people who clock up more actual ***miles travelled*** by plane or car than by foot. But is it meaningful to say that going from New York to London by air is "more popular" than going by foot? By characterising "on/by foot" as a "mode of transport", you're practically *forcing* "quirky phrasing".

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your answer. I feel that it's strange. That's why I asked the question. I just don't understand how to put it. Could you help me, please?

Comment: I don't really understand the context. What exactly is a "journey"? And does "most popular" mean the mode of travel that people ***like*** most, that they spend ***most time*** using, or that they travel the ***greatest distance*** by? Or indeed the mode of travel ***used by most people***, as in *More people walk to work than drive to work*.

Comment: You are correct.  It does not sound natural.  It would be more natural to say, *The second most popular way of **taking a journey** is **by** foot*.  That still sounds a bit weird as others have commented but at least it's understandable.  We *take* journeys.  We do not *make* them.

Comment: *making journeys* seems awkward in this context - can't put my finger on why, but it seems to imply more effort than just *journeying* in general. Also, a *journey* in common parlance typically refers to a longer trip (longer than most of us would be making on foot), but you'd need a look at the data to confirm what the author actually meant here. I'd also consider replacing *on foot* with *walking* (I'd assume running or hopping on one leg are statistically insignificant...)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've added a screenshot of the task. I hope it will make it clearer for you.

Comment: @EllieK thank you for the answer. It makes sense. I'm just wondering then why they wrote 'journeys **MADE** by different forms of transport' in the task? Also, could you, please, explain why you suggest writing 'by foot' but not 'on foot'?

Comment: With no information about what exactly a "journey" is (and very specifically, what is the ***average journey distance*** for each country contributing to the figures), I think that's a fairly pointless chart that probably isn't comparing like with like. And what are they counting anyway? Number of journeys? Miles travelled? ***Time*** spent travelling?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski thank you very much! 'Walking' definitely sounds better even to my non-native speaker's ear. :) I've pasted a screenshot of the writing task. Hope it will help you understand the context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers they count numbers of journeys, as I can understand from the task. Anyway, it's not my goal to judge the task. I think it's pretty irrelevant what kinds of journeys they meant. Students are assessed based on their ability to find the main features and tendencies in the chart and write a coherent, grammatically correct description.

Comment: My point is that the context itself (probably just a made-up chart, I doubt any real statistician would bother collecting such worthless numbers) isn't particularly realistic, so it's not a good "test" to see how people would use language to describe the "information" presented. After all, I can't help noticing that 3 out of the 4 countries there aren't at all Anglophone, and vast numbers of Canadians rarely or barely speak English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the countries might be not Anglophone, but I bet the task was created by native speakers. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think the "test" was set by a Dutchman keen to promote the fact that they don't / can't make so many car journeys in the Netherlands. But that's all by the bye.

Comment: @i_yre_b I'm wrong again (twice in the last week).  BrE does favor *make a journey* over *take a journey*.  It's perfectly fine.  *Journey on foot* works.  *Journey by foot* is better.  I walk around *on foot*.  I complete journeys *by foot*.

Comment: @i_yre_b Here is a link with more detail regarding *on foot* and *by foot*.  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/by-foot-vs-on-foot

Comment: @EllieK thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly valid English.

Personally, I would have been more likely to say, "The second most popular way of traveling is on foot". I suppose "making a journey" is an unusual phrase. In this case I think they said it that way because they wanted to match the labels on the chart. The chart says "Journeys made by", so they're just recasting that a bit to say "making a journey". If they had said "travelling" or "means of transport" or some other phrase, then a reader might wonder, "Does 'travelling' mean something different than 'making a journey'?"

When I'm making summary or conclusion statements like this based on data in a chart, I will often be careful to use very similar or exactly the same wording as the chart to avoid stumbling into a misinterpretation. I don't want to carelessly say "per capita income" when the chart said "family income", or "car owners" when the chart said "car drivers", etc. By the way, sometimes people do this sort of thing deliberately when they're trying to make a political or social point. Like quote some statistic about illegal immigrants and than talk as if that statistic applied to all immigrants, or vice versa. Or quote the results of a poll taken on one street corner in New York and casually talk as if that applied to all Americans. Etc. (I don't want to go into a detailed example because that would veer us off into a political debate.)

Comment: Good point about matching the labels on the chart. *Excellent* point about this sometimes being extra relevant because the existing "terminology" is being used in some "persuasive writing" context where even superficially trivial rephrasing might distort or lose some point being made (honestly or otherwise! :)

Comment: Thank you, Jay, for the comment. Even I try to use a wording similar to the task, but if you use it in every sentence, the description becomes awkward.